# mobile device if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

My plan was to replace an iframe in my html code with a paragraph if mobile device width is less than 480.  I wrote the following, but it is not working. Can anyone share what I did wrong?

```
// Small device

 if ($(window).width() < 480)  {

  $("#quiz-iframe iframe").replaceWith(function(){
        return $('<p>Please refer to Desktop or Tablet for the content.</p>');
    });

}
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why not use media queries?

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($(window).width() < 480)  {

    $("#quiz-iframe iframe")
        .replaceWith('<p>Please refer to Desktop or Tablet for the content.</p>');
}
```

Comment: How will this solve his problem? I agree that using a a function is unnecessary in his case, but it should still work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Barmar I don't think so. Maybe it's just me but I can't figure out what $ on the return value from his code is for.

Comment: `$("html code")` creates a jQuery object containing the elements created with that HTML.

Comment: Like when you write `$("#table").append($("<tr>"))`

Comment: @Barmar Okay, but I don't see the point of using it. Seems to me it's just a redundant. Plus, I've never used replaceWith() I just fixed a part which I think it need to be fixed from his code. If I'm wrong in some way, feel free to suggest another solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width < 480)
    {
        //do what you want here.
    }
});
```

Comment: If he's on a mobile device, he doesn't have to resize it for the window size to become small, it's already small when the page loads.

Comment: @Barmar yes... `resize` isn't needed.., but I added it there if the site that he is trying to develop is accessible in browsers....

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I used the resize function and it worked as expected. Thank you!

```
// Small device

$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
if(width < 480)
{
    $("#quiz-iframe iframe").replaceWith(function(){
        return $('<p>Please refer to Desktop or Tablet for quiz content.</p>');
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
if ($(window).width() < 480)  {

    $("#quiz-iframe iframe").html("<p>Please refer to Desktop or Tablet for the content.</p>");

}
```